# How to get the root URL to Slim application in a subdir?

Tags: .htaccess, twig, mamp, slim, subdirectory

I must make a website with PHP and I choose to use Slim and Twig. But my superiors don't want me to use a virtual host. So I'm having trouble when I test the website with MAMP because the site is on a subdirectory, like `http://localhost:8888/subdir`.

When I try to access an asset, I can't use absolute path because it would force me to write `/subpath/path/to/asset`. But when we will deploy the application, there will be no subpath. How can I root the website as if there would be a virtual host?

You can see some of my code below:

**index.php**

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; 

include 'database.php';

use app\controller\ConfigController;

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/', function () {
    echo "accueil";
})->name("root");

$app->group('/Admin', function () use ($app) {

    $app->get("/", function (){
        $ctrl = new ConfigController();
        $ctrl->index();
    })->name("indexAdmin");

});
```

**.htaccess** (in localhost:8888/subdir)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

**ConfigController** (called function)

```
public function index() {
    $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem("app/view/Admin");
    $twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader);
    $template = $twig->loadTemplate('Index.twig');
    echo $template->render(array(
        'css' => "admin.css"
    ));
}
```

**template** called by Twig environment

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app/assets/stylesheets/{{ css }}">
</head>
<body>
[...]
```

When I search on Google and Stack Overflow, everyone said to make a virtual host, but I can't. Would there be another solution?

Comment: Hey @Amanite, welcome to S.O. Are you using the `slim/views` package to integrate Twig in your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the [slim/views package](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Views) to integrate Twig in the application you are writing, it's possible to add the `TwigExtension` in that package to your Twig instance and use the `siteUrl` function for your assets. This way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ siteUrl('path/to/asset/style.css') }}">
```

If you're not using that package, you can create your own function to get the application URL. Something like this:

```
function siteUrl($url) {
    $req = Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $uri = $req->getUrl() . $req->getRootUri();
    return $uri . '/' . ltrim($url, '/');
}
```

Comment: Thank ypu vert much ! I will try thqt on monday (I dont have access to the project on the week end)